# HTTP Status code for preflight request

Tags: c#, .net, http, cors

this question was asked in some online test on some website but i did not found the correct answer. Can anyone help me to get the right answer.

Ques: What is the HTTP Status code for pre-flight request?

Comment: can you also explain term 'pre-flight' request?

Comment: Do you mean OPTIONS request in CORS workflow?

Comment: no i mean, why we have use the term 'pre-flight'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A successful pref-flight request returns status code 200 (OK).Indicating that CORS is enabled for the service.

Comment: Not going to downvote, but the spec says 200-220 for successful requests. You also have the other HTTP codes for other conditions, such as authentication or authorization errors.